# JavaScript body OnLoad Event is not triggered due to missing body tag

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to integrate 3D Secure payment logic with JavaScript.
As I post the credit card info to bank, I get a reply html; this html redirects the screen to 3D Password screen of the bank which is:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>MDpay default response template for web</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#02014E" OnLoad="OnLoadEvent();" >
    <form name="downloadForm" action="https://katmai.est.com.tr/mdpayacs/pareq" method="POST">
     <!-- Some Input Fields -->
    </form>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" >
    
    
    function OnLoadEvent() {
    document.downloadForm.submit();
    }
    
    </SCRIPT>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If we want to open this html in a pop up screen, `OnLoadEvent` does not get triggered with:

```
var popup = window.open('','');
popup.document.write("'"+data+"'");
popup.focus();
```

but if this does work which is everything good. I call the `onload` function in body so I don't care what is the function to be called in `OnLoad`.

```
var popup = window.open('','');
popup.document.write("'"+data+"'");
popup.document.body.onload();
popup.focus()
```

BUT, we don't want to do this in popup, we don't want to open a new tab or page. We want to do this on same screen that we get the values from the user, so I write the returning html to a div, but because there can be no two body tags in one html, the browser does not include the new body tag which includes `OnLoad` function name:

```
document.getElementById('vpos').innerHTML=data;
document.downloadForm.submit() 
// this is the code that works in OnLoad function.if a write that code statically of course it works, but this code logic can always change.
```

How will I solve this? Hope I am clear.

Comment: create an iframe instead of div?

Comment: Could You explain how you got 'data' ?

Comment: eliminate onload from the HTML in <body ...> and instead set up the event handlers only in Javascript.

Comment: i also tried that, but not a great practice I guess.

Comment: ı get the data from the server. Server sends it to me, ı get it with post function

Comment: @Paul How can I eliminate it, bank sends it to me by that way

Comment: Ah, well that is a problem. I thought you had control. My fault for not reading carefully.

Comment: Hi,

how did you solved this issue